# Magento 1.9, php 5.6 - Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade, zend-framework, php-5.6

Have the same with Magento CE 1.8 and 1.9

After update php from 5.5.16 to 5.6.0 on my VPS I got this 2 errors in [magento]/var/log/system.log:

```
ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated  in [magento]/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 311
ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated  in [magento]/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 472
```

I was find this info https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/pull/347
But all variations in php.ini changes not work for me (I was restarted php-fpm service after each changes in php.ini, of course).

Here https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/pull/347/files#r14075423 I read suggested changes exactly in this lines (313 and 474) but I don't want use any hacks to Magento Core files.

In frontend and backend I don't see any problems with encoding - all looks fine (I have Russian localizations - frontend and admin panel).

May I ignore this ERR in system.log or not? What the right way to correct this error?

Comment: This should be addressed in 1.9.2+ where various lib/Zend files test for PHP version 5.6 and above to use the new method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think you are supposed to use Magento with php 5.6 yet.
I assume there will be an official statement when Magento will support php 5.6 and an offical patch if necessary.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I thought I'd point out that the answer from Alex below (http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82410/2142) helped me patch a Magento EE 1.13.1 site to not throw those errors when using PHP 5.6

Answer (score 55):

You can use the following patch:

- [0001-BUGIFX-Magento-Zend-Framework-1-PHP5.6.patch](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/renttek/29beaaa1e90909639501/raw/be5df0b33b72cdc2ab037d374802c53ccba066df/0001-BUGIFX-Magento-Zend-Framework-1-PHP5.6.patch)

It is from the full Github-Gist:

> Bugfix for Zend Framework 1 in Magento (>= 1.7.*.*) + PHP 5.6
>
> https://gist.github.com/renttek/29beaaa1e90909639501

Comment: Worked like a charm, save the file to Magento root and run this command `patch -p1 < 0001-BUGIFX-Magento-Zend-Framework-1-PHP5.6.patch` kudos to [@mautz-et-tong](https://github.com/mautz-et-tong)

Comment: I missed the "p1" parameter - thanks for that

Comment: I ran this successfully, but the error persists.

Comment: @ol'bobdole Which error? Did you use compilation? you might need to compile again.

Comment: @Alex Good point! I believe this is it.

Comment: This should be the accepted response (the one from Marius is outdated)

Answer (score 17):

You need to change `lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php` and replace the `internal_encoding` related calls with `ini_get('default_encoding')`
and all the other occurences in the Zend framework also...

Comment: This become very helpful for me - when I try to install old 1.4.0.1 version to dev server for migration to never version. Thanks!

Comment: The problem itself is not Magento + PHP 5.6 but Zend Framework that is coming with magento + PHP 5.6

Comment: In here there is a gist for an easy replacement with sed on the commandline https://gist.github.com/nhp/326c2b03b2e88ff48d20

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.6 deprecated a few functions, especially the one Zend is using:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php#migration56.deprecated.iconv-mbstring-encoding

If I understand this correctly, you just have to set [default_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset), then the call of the method is not needed anymore.

Comment: Yes, I was try set default_encoding to "UTF-8" and comment all 3 strings (iconv.*) in php.ini but this error still exist. Think that need back to php 5.5.16 and wait for Magento support php 5.6 (as Marius suggested). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this shell script from your Magento root directory to get rid of this message if you're running OSX: https://gist.github.com/jayelkaake/34109641e5489e3e7e30

Note that it will modify some files in your lib/ folder, so any updates to Magento will overwrite them (though I really hope Magento fixes the bug and adds official PHP 5.6.9 compatibility in their next version).

Comment: For which Magento Version did you try this? Does not seem to work for me.

Comment: v1.9 - it only works on OSX though. [This one](https://gist.github.com/jayelkaake/3ab168117d653cf4e092) should work for non-OSX unix machines.

Comment: I just think it needs more than this replace.see the patch I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the system encoding php.ini was already set to UTF-8, so in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php I added:-

```
if($oenc != 'UTF-8') iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
....
if($oenc != 'UTF-8') iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', $oenc);
```

And the same thing in lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php

In you php.ini file, make sure the value `default_charset="UTF-8"` even on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

1. Create the following folders:

   - /app/code/local/Zend/Locale
   - /app/code/local/Zend/Service
   - /app/code/local/Zend/Validate
   - /app/code/local/Zend/XmlRpc
2. Copy the following files from /lib/Zend/ to /app/code/local/Zend/:

   - Locale/Format.php
   - Service/Audioscrobbler.php
   - Service/Technorati.php
   - Validate/Hostname.php
   - Validate/StringLength.php
   - XmlRpc/Client.php
3. Open the files from /app/code/local/Zend/ in a text editor and search for "internal_encoding" and replace them with "default_charset". Before doing this, make sure that the “internal_encoding” string is a parameter of an iconv related function. Don’t replace "mb_internal_encoding", "$internal_encoding" or any other non iconv related stuff, because it will break the code.

Source: https://www.code007.ro/how-to-fix-php-5-6-deprecated-messages-in-magento/

Answer (score -2):

If you need quick fix you can replace in index.php line (about 40):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

with:

```
error_reporting((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

This should "hide" notifications/errors about deprecated functions.

Notice: This is not a real fix, this is just hiding notice/information about this problem with iconv_set_encoding()

Worked for me on Magento 1.8.1.0

Answer (score -3):

just install php gd library using relevant command

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd` of `php5-gd`

or say for the RehHat

`sudo yum install php56-gd` or `php5-gd`

and now restart the apache and you are good to go with as usual.