# Magento 1.9.x and PHP? I had 5.5, now upgraded to 5.6 and it seems to work! Is that OK or shall I switch back to PHP 5.5?

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, hosting, php-5.5

I currently have `Magento version 1.9.1.0` on store/domain1 which I plan to eventually upgrade to `Magento version 1.9.2.4.` Now , I also want to install the latest version of `Magento Community Edition (2.1)` to a different domain/account on the same VPS server so my hosting company installed the cPanel supported easyapache 4 method which should give me the option to select different versions of PHP on different accounts/domains.

**I had this on my 1.9.1.0 store:**

```
Apache Version  2.2.29
PHP Version 5.5.27
MySQL Version   5.6.30
```

**Now it has this:**

```
Apache Version  2.4.23
PHP Version 5.6.24
MySQL Version   5.6.30
```

The funny thing is that it actually seems to work fine! Is this OK or shall I revert that account `Magento 1.9.1.0` back to `PHP 5.5`?

What is the difference anyways?

Answer (score 3):

Magento 1.9.2.3 forward will work with PHP 5.6 as it tests for the following:

```
  $origenc = PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600
                    ? iconv_get_encoding('internal_encoding')
                    : ini_get('default_charset');
        if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600) {
            iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
        }
```

From post by [Edmonds Commerce for Magento support](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento-1.9.2.3-fixes-php-5.6-compatibility/).

Previous 1.9 versions may run into the following => [Magento 1.9, php 5.6 - Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/magento-1-9-php-5-6-use-of-iconv-internal-encoding-is-deprecated) and have that issue addressed per that thread.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible I would even upgrade to PHP7. You only need to install the Inchoo Php7 module in order to let it work with magento 1.9

That module can be found on github: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

You will notice a huge benefit in speed from PHP 7