# Magento 1.7 on php5.6

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.6

I'm running Magento 1.7 on php6.5, which was previously on php5.3.

First problem, Deprecated functionality: iconv_set_encoding(),  was solved with this: [Magento 1.9, php 5.6 - Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/magento-1-9-php-5-6-use-of-iconv-internal-encoding-is-deprecated)

Now I've got a new error message:

```
ini_set(): Cannot find save handler 'memcache'  in /var/www/rkbridal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

How to work through this?

Comment: I think the problem is in session save path. can you check apache server where you are configured session savepath.

Comment: We need to configure memcahe. for more information https://coderkelly.wordpress.com/tag/memcached/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a single server, I would just configure sessions to use the file system. In you app/etc/local.xml set session_save to files (see below). If you have the memory on your server setup you could mount the var/session and var/cache to memory using tmpfs. See https://www.prohost.be/magento-tmpfs-ramdrive-varcache-and-varsessions/ for details.

```
<config>
<global>
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Tue, 07 Oct 2014 02:55:25 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[magentodb]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
  <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have just disabled memcache and session_save in local.xml for local development purposes.