# Unable to install magento 1.4 on xammp with PHP Version 5.6.34?

Tags: error, installation, magento-1.4, xampp, php-5.6

On installing magento 1.4 on localhost i am getting an error as shown below

[image]

and there is back end message generate for this #406715812 error :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:160:"Deprecated functionality: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated  in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\lib\Zend\Validate\Hostname.php on line 438";i:1;s:1575:"#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(8192, 'iconv_set_encod...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 438, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\lib\Zend\Validate\Hostname.php(438): iconv_set_encoding('internal_encodi...', 'UTF-8')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\lib\Zend\Validate\EmailAddress.php(201): Zend_Validate_Hostname->isValid('gmail.com')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\lib\Zend\Validate.php(212): Zend_Validate_EmailAddress->isValid('anilthakur.matr...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Admin\Model\User.php(392): Zend_Validate::is('anilthakur.matr...', 'EmailAddress')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Install\Model\Installer.php(220): Mage_Admin_Model_User->validate()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Install\controllers\WizardController.php(390): Mage_Install_Model_Installer->validateAndPrepareAdministrator(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Install_WizardController->administratorPostAction()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('administratorPo...')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\index.php(78): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:49:"/shop/index.php/install/wizard/administratorPost/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Please help to install Magento 1.4 on xammp server with PHP Version 5.6.34

Comment: The error is simply telling that your Magento version and PHP version are not compatible.

Comment: Please check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Although, as per devdocs, Magento 1.4.x is not compatible with PHP 5.6.x, you can try the fixes mentioned in the link below to make it work:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/renttek/29beaaa1e90909639501/raw/be5df0b33b72cdc2ab037d374802c53ccba066df/0001-BUGIFX-Magento-Zend-Framework-1-PHP5.6.patch

**Notice:** Don't make changes in the core file of Magento directly.

There are many similar questions asked before. You can take a look at the following links for reference:

- [Magento 1.9, php 5.6 - Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/magento-1-9-php-5-6-use-of-iconv-internal-encoding-is-deprecated)
- https://www.code007.ro/how-to-fix-php-5-6-deprecated-messages-in-magento/